# How can I create a Kentucky Map by Zip Code in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, zipcode

Suppose I have a dataframe containing Kentucky zip codes and values between -1 and 1. I want to plot these as a heatmap of Kentucky, where -1 represents the lowest color of the gradient and 1 represents the highest.

How can I do this in R? I'm using R Studio 1.3.959 (R version 3.6.3).

Answer (score 0):

An option using `tigris` and `sf`. Note that this uses zip code tabulation areas, which are not a 1:1 match with zip codes. Zip codes follow streets and can't be made into sensible polygons: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2693/162034

```r
library(tigris)
library(sf)

# download zipcode tabulation areas and state boundaries
zcta1 <- zctas(TRUE)
sts <- states(TRUE)

# subset zipcode data
zcta_ky <- st_intersection(zcta1, sts[sts$NAME == 'Kentucky', ])

# add random 0-1 field
zcta_ky$rand <- runif(nrow(zcta_ky))

#plot
plot(zcta_ky['rand'])
```

[image]